# How to find Taylor series for $\ln(1+2x)$ using power series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: summation, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm asked to find the Taylor-series to

$f(x)=\ln(1+2x)$ about $x=0$ using the power series to $\frac{1}{1-x}$. And then I must find the biggest number of $n$ necessary to estimate $\ln(1.02),$ where the biggest error can be $2.0 \times 10^{-6}.$

So I think I must integrate

$\int{\frac{1}{1-x}}dx=-\ln(1-x)=\sum \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$

And then I'm stuck. I really don't understand how to use that power serie to find the Taylor series.

Comment: Make the substitution $p=-2x$ in $\ln (1-p)$.

Comment: If ${1 \over 1-y} = \sum_k y^k$ then $f'(x) = {2 \over 1+2x} = \sum_k (-2x)^k$.

Comment: @copper.hat. Hmm, I understand about half. I do know that $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum x^n$ But when you write $f'(x) = {2 \over 1+2x}$ What about the number 2 on top in the fraction?

Comment: Compute $f'(x)$. Substitute $y=-2x$. Also, I made a mistake, I am missing a factor of $2$ in the last sum, it should be $2 \sum_k (-2x)^k$.

Comment: @copper.hat. The taylor series is given as $\sum \frac{f^k(c}{k!} (x-c)^k$. But how is the sum we found right given that we only calculted the first derivative, and did not find the n-th derivate? I'm not saying they answer we found was wrong, I'm just trying to understand how finding taylor series in general by using power series work

Comment: $f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t)dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the power series $\frac1{1-t} = 1 + t + t^2 + t^3+...$ to express

$$\ln(1-y) = -\int_0^y \frac1{1-t} dt = -\int_0^y ( 1 + t + t^2 + ...) dt 
=-y-\frac12 y^2 - \frac 13 y^3+...$$

Then, set $y = -2x$ to get the series for $\ln(1+2x)$,
$$\ln(1+2x) = 2x-2x^2+\frac83 x^3+...$$

Plug in $x=0.01$ to approximate $\ln(1.02)$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you mean. But I will write it like this, and please correct me if I'm wrong

$ln(x-1)=-\int_0^y \frac1{1-t} dt=-\int\sum x^n$
$$-\int\sum x^n= -\sum \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
And the I set $x=-2x$ ??

Comment: And then I get that the serie is $$-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-2x)^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Comment: But there is something that's not right about the formula I made. Because the Taylor serie to $$f(x)=ln(1+2x)=f(c)+f'(c)(x-c)+.....$$
But my serie starts right at $f'(c)(x-c)$. I know that the first term will be $0$, but still, shouldn't my formula give $0$ due to the index $0$ ??

Comment: @Mathomat55 - it is fine, and actually more formal, to write it in the Sigma notation. My expressions are the ease of understanding.

Comment: @Mathomat55 - Note the leading term vanishes, i.e. $\ln(1) = 0$.

Comment: I know that the leading term will vanish, but shouldn't my formula give 0 if I plugg in $n=0$ still? Or is it just supposed to give you the first none-zero term?